# AlpineJS x-data overwritten

Tags: javascript, laravel, tailwind-css, alpine.js

I have the following HTML structure:

```html
<div x-data="{selected: 0}">
    <div x-data="{ open: false }"
        @click="open = !open; selected !== 1 ? selected = 1 : selected = 0;"
    >
        test
    </div>
    <div x-data="{ open: false }"
        @click="open = !open; selected !== 2 ? selected = 2 : selected = 0;"
    >
        test
    </div>
</div>
```

The problem is the the first x-data with the selected is no longer there after I write in the div children x-data. I think it is right to say I overwrite it. So the question is, how can I prevent this from happening? I want to be able to keep the open and also to update the selected. thank you

Answer (score 0):

> Alpine.js, unlike React or Vue, doesn’t provide any parent-child
> communication patterns or primitives. “Alpine components” don’t
> receive any context from parent components, each component has its own
> individual and independent scope which means nesting doesn’t work as
> you would expect coming from Vue/React or even JavaScript (JavaScript
> has lexical scoping, Alpine does not).
>
> That means that in Alpine.js there’s no parent-child component
> communication only “sibling” component communication. For sibling
> communication, the pattern often proposed in issues by Caleb (the
> creator of Alpine.js) and other contributors is to use the window or
> document as an event bus.

Source: https://codewithhugo.com/alpinejs-component-communication-event-bus/

Here is a code example that they name:

```js
<div x-data="{ isOpen: false }">
  <!-- this component can be shown/hidden using a `toggle` event  -->
  <div
    x-show="isOpen"
    x-on:toggle.window="isOpen = !isOpen"
    role="alert"
    >
    <p>This alert is toggled when `toggle` events are dispatched.</p>
    <button @click="isOpen = false">close alert</button>
  </div>
</div>
<div x-data="{}">
  <p>The button in this component can toggle the "alert".</p>
  <button @click="$dispatch('toggle')">Toggle alert</button>
</div>
<div x-data="{}">
  <p>The button in this component can <strong>also</strong> toggle the "alert".</p>
  <button @click="$dispatch('toggle')">Toggle alert 2</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I did a lot of research yesterday and yes, AlpineJS is not as React/Vue/Angular but I have a working solution and this is something like this:

```
<div
    x-data="{ count : 0 }"
    x-init="$watch('count', val => $dispatch('new-count', val))"
    x-on:increment="count++"
    x-on:decrement="count--"
>
    <div>In root component: <span x-text="count"></span></div>
        <div
        x-data="{ count: 0 }"
        x-on:new-count.window="count = $event.detail"
    >
        <div>In nested component <span x-text="count"></span></div>
        <button x-on:click="$dispatch('increment')">Increment</button>
        <button x-on:click="$dispatch('decrement')">Decrement</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Use a `$dispatch` and in the parent use a `$watch` and inside it make another `$dispatch` with another event name. The piece of the puzzle is to listen to the event but on the `window` level. Not ideal, but working. I hope it helps also someone else.

Answer (score 0):

In Alpine.js your data is encapsulated inside the component (meaning no parent components will see it) and a nested component also will NOT see the parent components data either.

At the moment, this feature is not on the roadmap. See this Github discussion [here](https://github.com/alpinejs/alpine/issues/49).

**Event bus approach**

One approach would be to leverage Alpine.js `$dispatch` magic property and use an event listener somewhere else with either `x-on:` or the `@` alias.

```
<!-- Parent component -->
<div id="papa" x-data="{isTired: false}" x-on:cry.window="isTired = true">
  <span x-text="'Papa is tired: ' + isTired"></span>
  <!-- New child component scope -->
  <div id="baby" x-data="">
    <button @click="$dispatch('cry')">Make Baby Cry</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

[CodePen Demo](https://codepen.io/James0r/pen/yLMyXNM?editors=1111)

This takes advantage of native browser event [bubbling and capturing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#bubbling_and_capturing_explained).

**State management store approach**

If you're familiar with frameworks like React or Vue.js, you're probably familiar with state management libraries like Redux or Vuex.

[Spruce](https://spruce.ryangjchandler.co.uk/) is a lean version of something like this for Alpine.js, and would offer the benefit of allowing you to share data between components with ease.

You can see an example of communication between components in their [getting started guide](https://spruce.ryangjchandler.co.uk/quick-start).